# Rotating media on webpage reload

Tags: javascript, html, web, ads

I am working on a website with a space for an advertisement on the side. I want to be able to display a different advert each time the page is loaded. I know how to do this if the adverts are purely images, but I also want some of these to be youtube videos or other media sources.

I want to use javascript for this, but I would like to use as little scripting as possible.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

For images, I would use something like the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//Random Banner image on Page Reload

//store the images in arrays below

images = new Array(5);

images[0] = "<a href='http://www.example.com'><img src='some_image.gif'/></a>";

images[1] = "<a href='http://www.example.com'><img src='some_image.gif'/></a>";

images[2] = "<a href='http://www.example.com'><img src='some_image.gif'/></a>";

images[3] = "<a href='http://www.example.com'><img src='some_image.gif'/></a>";

images[4] = "<a href='http://www.example.com'><img src='some_image.gif'/></a>";

index = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);

document.write(images[index]);
</script>
```

Comment: You say you know how to do this for images. Can you share some code for how you would do it for images? Perhaps we could then augment that to add video and etc.

Comment: @Bart done :) any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Augmenting the logic you already have, you could just add the markup for a youtube video like this (using the [YouTube iframe api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)):

```
images[5] = '<iframe type="text/html" width="640" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/u1zgFlCw8Aw?enablejsapi=1&origin=http://example.com" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
```

Is there a specific reason you want to do this in JavaScript? Seems like it might be more suited to a server side technology.

Comment: not especially - if there's a better way to do it then by all means I'd be happy to hear about it. The video doesn't necessarily come from youtube though.